Filter rows based off selected date for Paginated Report/SSRS to get a historical snapshot of what the org looked like at that selected time
I have a table of employees summarized like below that is connected to a Power BI dataset. The business is asking for an exported paginated report to be able to filter this data to a certain date to go back in time to see what the company looked like. For example, if they filtered to 11/20/2023 it would show rows 2,4, and 6. But if it was 12/31/2023, only 4 and 6 would show etc. I did something similar in Power BI which is also connected to the same dataset where I added a Calendar table and put a measure that was written like this:
HistoricalDate = IF(MAX(Table[Effective Date]) <= MAX('Calendar'[Date]) && MAX(Table[Effective To]) >= MAX('Calendar'[Date]),1,0)
With that measure being filtered to 1 for every visual on the Power BI, it works exactly how I want/expect. I just don't know how to use that same logic or different workaround to do something similar with the Paginated Report since I have little experience. I brought the data in but wasn't sure if I should use that same measure somehow or how to do a parameter with it with my embedded Paginated Report in the Power BI report.
Thanks in advance for the help.


Assuming it's a simple SQL Table and the date columns are actually dates then something like SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE @myDataParm BETWEEN [Effective Date] and [Effective To] should work.

@AlanSchofield thank you so much, didn't realize it would be that simple...I was able to switch my datasource from a Power BI dataset to SQL to get it to work with your solution. Thanks again
